# Add Multiple series to a chart dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to add dynamic series in the chart.

I have a data like date,totalamount. i would like to plot those points on chart.

I get the data from sql database and bind.

i want to plot the data from datatable which will update dynamically.

```
Series newSeries=new Series();
newseries.ChartType=SeriesChartType.Line;
newSeries.BorderWidth = 3;
Chart1.Series.Add(newSeries);
newSeries.XValueMember = "date1";
newSeries.YValueMembers = "total";
Chart1.DataBind();
```

this is plotting at last series of the tree view.
please help me on this?

Comment: you can try asp.net chart control http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: i am already using asp.net chart control. while adding the data to series i am unable to bind dinamic data from datatable i would like to   add dynamic series with same datatable which is calling at loop. so it is always updated data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 foreach(DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables["Query"].Rows)
    {
        // For each Row add a new series
        string seriesName = row["SalesRep"].ToString();
        Chart1.Series.Add(seriesName);
        Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        Chart1.Series[seriesName].BorderWidth = 2;

        for(int colIndex = 1; colIndex < myDataSet.Tables["Query"].Columns.Count; colIndex++)
        {
            // For each column (column 1 and onward) add the value as a point
            string columnName = myDataSet.Tables["Query"].Columns[colIndex].ColumnName;
            int YVal = (int) row[columnName];

            Chart1.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(columnName, YVal);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,Please don’t forget to click on answer if this solution worked for you

Comment: here my chart plotting is working fine. but at the end of the chart grid line not clear

Comment: I think may be interval issue, you can use following options Chart1.ChartAreas["Area1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled 
chtMain.ChartAreas["Area1"].AxisX.Interval = 120 also  if possible attach image,so get better idea of issue

Comment: This code works fine but I want to show the legend and its show two time because I have two series. How is it possible to show the legend one time for all series??